# What's limiting the amount of rows I can insert in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do an 11,000 row insert, and when I execute the query, it runs smoothly but only inserts ~100 rows. The amount of rows it can insert changes a little bit depending on how much data / columns a row has, but it only fluctuates from 100-200 rows or so.

I'm using

```
INSERT INTO ...
VALUES
    (...),
    (...),
    ...
```

I've already made the max_allowed_packet setting huge, but it didn't change the amount of rows inserted. What other settings govern how much data you can insert?

Comment: **How** are you inserting this data?

Comment: Just updated my question

Comment: Do you have any auto-increment columns, are the data types correct, are any errors thrown?

Comment: Aparently no problem with this quantity of rows. I don´t know any limit. Can you place the code you are using to insert the rows?

Comment: There is an auto-incremented row, all the data is correct, otherwise there'd be an error

Comment: Why is this question getting so heavily downvoted?

Comment: this question is really to broad... this could be an MySQL config problem / over indexing problem...

Comment: I think it's downvoted because people are thinking too broadly about a more specific question. Are there any other settings that can affect the insert limit? It's not clear searching the web, maybe because I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. I'm not asking about indexing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following link: [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,161869)

In general the answer is infinite.